# Trying to pass S3 bucket names and folder paths as command-line arguments to python scripts on EMR via AWS CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am attempting to pass the bucket names and folder names to my python scripts, via the AWS CLI as follows:

`aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-12XXXXXXXXX2R --steps Type=spark,Name=step0_do_something,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--conf,spark.yarn.appExecutorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp,--conf,spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp,--conf,spark.executorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp,--conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true,--conf,spark.master=yarn,--py-files,s3://com.some.bucketname/scripts/my_modules.egg,s3://com.some.bucketname/scripts/my_steps/step0_do_something.py com.another.bucketname an_input_filename.csv somefoldername/somesubfoldername],ActionOnFailure=CANCEL_AND_WAIT`

My approach was to capture the 3 strings ('com.another.bucketname', 'an_input_filename.csv' and 'somefoldername/somesubfoldername' within the script (step0_do_something.py) in the following way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = start_spark_session()
    print(sys.argv[0])
    print(sys.argv[1])
    print(sys.argv[2])
```

However, all I get is the following error message:

```
Error parsing parameter '--steps': Expected: ',', received: 'EOF' for input:
Type=spark,Name=step0_do_something,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--conf,spark.yarn.appExecutorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp,--conf,spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp,--conf,spark.executorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp,--conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true,--conf,spark.master=yarn,--py-files,s3://com.some.bucketname/scripts/my_modules.egg,s3://com.some.bucketname/scripts/my_steps/step0_do_something.py
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^
```

May be worth mentioning that the above aws emr add-steps command *without* the 3 parameters at the end ('com.another.bucketname', 'an_input_filename.csv' and 'somefoldername/somesubfoldername') is what I've been using to submit the step to an aws emr cluster without any problems (but having to use hard-coded bucket and folder names). So my failed attempt to add some parameters in this way is definitely the cause of the error. I just cannot find any description of how to achieve this on the aws documentation pages or elsewhere. 
Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, by just replacing the spaces between the script name and the 3 strings with commas:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-12XXXXXXXXX2R --steps Type=spark,Name=step0_do_something,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--conf,spark.yarn.appExecutorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp,--conf,spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp,--conf,spark.executorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp,--conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true,--conf,spark.master=yarn,--py-files,s3://com.some.bucketname/scripts/my_modules.egg,s3://com.some.bucketname/scripts/my_steps/step0_do_something.py**,**com.another.bucketname**,**an_input_filename.csv**,**somefoldername/somesubfoldername],ActionOnFailure=CANCEL_AND_WAIT
```

Comment: So, are these strings stored in sys.argv[0], ..., sys.argv[2]?

Comment: Yes, they are passed to sys.argv[0].. etc, in the python script specified (step0_do_something.py).